# SIM800L is not registering on network

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, network

I'm testing SIM800L module by registering to network manually and I'm getting an `error` message.
Here are the commands I tried.

```
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 31,0

OK

AT+CBAND?

+CBAND: EGSM_MODE,ALL_BAND

OK



AT+COPS=?

+COPS: (1,"Bharat Karnataka","CellOne","40471"),(2,"Airtel","AIRTEL","40445"),(3,"Hutch-Kamataka","HUTCH","40486"),,(0-4),(0-2)

OK

AT+COPS=1,1,"40471"    

ERROR
```

`AT+COPS=1,1,"40471"`  is this command right? My 
SIM card is CellOne and it's 4G.

Power supply -7.4 li-ion 1100mAh battery with an adjustable 5V-5A buck converter(3.8v is supplied to SIM800L)

Answer (score 1):

For the `AT+COPS` command you are setting manual with long alphanumeric network name but then using the numeric network name. Try `AT+COPS=1,2,"40471"`

[REF](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcops-plmn-selection/)

```
//Manually select T-mobile as carrier using short format alphanumeric network name
AT+COPS=1,0,"TMO"

//Manually select T-mobile as carrier using long format alphanumeric network name
AT+COPS=1,1,"T-Mobile USA"

//Manually select T-mobile as carrier using numeric network name
AT+COPS=1,2,"310260"
```

---

`AT+CSQ` checks the signal strength, you can check the reply range with a question mark,

```
AT+CSQ=?

+CSQ: (0-31,99),(0-7,99)

OK
```

The first number, 31, shows you have a good signal strength locally.

---

`AT+CBAND?` shows the mobile operating band set

---

`AT+COPS=?` will search for networks, your response indicates you found a few.